# Horizontal alignment of stacked premises in prftree

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to create an inference rule roughly similar to this one from the book "Implementing Programming Languages" by Aarne Ranta:

[image: inference rule with nice alignment of premises]

I want that nice horizontal alignment on the `\vdash` character in the premises. I'm using the `prftree` package, and the [documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/prftree/prftreedoc.pdf) mentions specifically in section 10 that there is no built-in feature for achieving this.

To simulate the look, I'm trying to use two `\prfStackPremises` next to each other, one for the environments (the `\gamma`s) and one for the evaluations. This is almost working, but I can't get the environments to be right-aligned and the evaluations left-aligned like they are in the above image. Here's a MWE of what I have right now:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prftree}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{prfenv}
    \prftree[r]{\textsc{EApp}}
    {
        \prfStackPremises
        {\gamma}
        {\gamma_1}
        {\dots}
        {\gamma_{n-1}}
        {\gamma \triangleright id_1 := v_1, \dots, id_n := v_n}
    }
    {
        \prfStackPremises
        {\vdash_e e_1 \Downarrow \langle v_1,\gamma_1 \rangle}
        {\vdash_e e_2 \Downarrow \langle v_2,\gamma_2 \rangle}
        {\dots}
        {\vdash_e e_n \Downarrow \langle v_n,\gamma_n \rangle}
        {\vdash_s stmts \Downarrow \langle v, \gamma' \rangle}
    }
    {\gamma \vdash_e id(e_1, \dots, e_n) \Downarrow \gamma''}
\end{prfenv}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

And here is what that typesets as:

[image: inference rule with center alignment of premises]

As you can see, the stacked premises are center-aligned, when I'd like them to be right- and left-aligned, respectively.

I've tried using `\hfill` and `\tag*{}` to no avail. I also looked in the documentation for any mention of horizontal alignment and didn't see anything. I'm willing to use another package if it would make this simpler. Thank you in advance for any help achieving this!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you for the heads up! Updated with a full MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ebproof` is exactly what I ended up needing. It has alignment built in! Here's the fixed version of that MWE, with alignment characters next to each of the `vdash`es:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{\gamma &\vdash_e e_1 \Downarrow \langle v_1,\gamma_1 \rangle}
    \infer[no rule]1{\gamma_1 &\vdash_e e_2 \Downarrow \langle v_2,\gamma_2 \rangle}
    \infer[no rule]1{\vdots&}
    \infer[no rule]1{\gamma_{n-1} &\vdash_e e_n \Downarrow \langle v_n,\gamma_n \rangle}
    \infer[no rule]1{\gamma \triangleright id_1 := v_1, \dots, id_n := v_n &\vdash_s stmts \Downarrow \langle v, \gamma'\rangle}
    \infer1[\textsc{EApp}]{\gamma \vdash_e id(e_1, \dots, e_n) \Downarrow \langle v,\gamma_n \rangle}
\end{prooftree}
\]
\end{document}
```

Which typesets as:

[image: inference rule with horizontally aligned vdashes]